# Handling a custom class using UIGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom class created as a subclass of UIImageView. I am trying to create an action attached to UIPanGestureRecognizer for an instance of this class (the object is called token.

```
let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"handleTokenDrag:test")
token.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

In the handler function (handleTokenDrag) I have access to the view associated with this object, but not to the object itself. How do I access the object so I can call its methods and modify its properties?

```
func handleTokenDrag(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer){...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the handleTokenDrag you can get your view directly from recognizer by doing so

```
func handleTokenDrag(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    if let myView = recognizer.view as? MyCustomImageView{

        myView.customProperty = someValue
    }
}
```